# How many $x$ satisfy $\mathbb{Q}(x)=\mathbb{Q}(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $z:=\exp{(2πi/7)}$, and $X:=\{ \sum _{j=1}^6 a_j z^j|a_j=0,1\}$
Then, how many $x\in X$ satisfy $\mathbb{Q}(x)=\mathbb{Q}(z)$ ?

It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}(x) \subset \mathbb{Q}(z)$. If $p(t) \in \mathbb{Q}(t)$ s.t., $p(x)=z$, $\mathbb{Q}(x)=\mathbb{Q}(z)$

I know $z^n$($n=1,\dots ,6$) satisfy it since $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ is a field. But I don't know how to check another elements.

Comment: One straightforward way of checking on an element by element basis that might give you some ideas on how to do it procedurally: $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ will equal $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ iff the powers $x^0, x^1, \ldots, x^6$ of $x$ form a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(z)$ iff the matrix of entries of the powers of $x$ in terms of powers of $z$ is invertible...

Comment: What is $[\Bbb Q(z):\Bbb Q]$ and what could $[\Bbb Q(x):\Bbb Q]$ possibly be? Note that for $H<G$, something like $\sum_{h\in H}h(z)$ will be $H$ invariant